# Array print element index 0 as index 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, element

How can I print the output as

17 in 1 days

21 in 2 days

23 in 3 days

**and not**

17 in 0 days

21 in 1 days

23 in 2 days

```
const arr = [17, 21, 23];

const printForecase = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(`${arr[i]} in ${i} days`);
    } } 
printForecase();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the index starts from 0, you just need to add one (1) when you print it in your `console.log()` (`${i+1}`)

```js
const arr = [17, 21, 23];

const printForecase = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(`${arr[i]} in ${i+1} days`);
    } } 
printForecase();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add 1 to the embedded expression ${i} so that it is ${i+1}

```js
const arr = [17, 21, 23];

const printForecase = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(`${arr[i]} in ${i+1} days`);
    } } 
printForecase();
```

Comment: Hii johnny , A small doubt, Won't the second method start to print from 21 instead of 17. Array indexes starts from zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add 1 with {i}

```
const arr = [17, 21, 23];

const printForecase = function() {
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${arr[i]} in ${i+1} days`);
} } 
printForecase();
```

**console.log(`${arr[i]} in ${i+1} days`)**

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [17,21,23];
const printForecase = ()=>{
        let days = 1;
        for(let newarr of arr){
           console.log(`${newarr} in ${ days++ } Days`)
        }
}

printForecase()
```